# Unable to create AVD manager - Configuration area not writable

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I can't create an AVD Manager. I've tried via 'Create new Android Device Manager' menu option, but when I hit OK nothing happens.
If I run the monitor file in the tools folder I get an error saying that the configuration area at /Users/user_name/.eclipse/ is not writable.

That makes sense, because I am running OSX 10.9.3 Mavericks and directories at the top levels of the file system are not writable. Logging in as root didn't help. Does anyone know how to choose a writable location for the config area? I've tried researching the issue but couldn't find any meaningful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo chmod -R +w <directory>`
or
`sudo chmod -R 660 <directory>`

from the terminal to make it writable

Comment: Thanks, I might try this as a last resort (I read somewhere that it could damage the Time Machine back-up system) so I would prefer to change the default location for Android Virtual Devices to a writable folder. Do you know of a workaround for this? Thanks again.

Comment: you could also just run avd as root if you feel like living dangerously. Otherwise USE GENYMOTION. It's at least 11,000,000 times more awesome than AVD.

Comment: I've tried setting the path where the new AVD will be created via the -p option but I get an error saying ~/.android/avd/myAVD.ini (No such file or directory).

Comment: Solved, I can create AVDs now. To create an AVD, android attempts to write files in the home folder of the current user. In my case, the home folder was not writable. I logged in as root and changed the owner of the home folder from 'staff' to me, using the chown command.  Here is an excellent tutorial on how to do this in a bash shell : http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/linuxcommand.org/lts0070.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I can create AVDs now. To create an AVD, android attempts to write files in the home folder of the current user. In my case, the home folder was not writable. I logged in as root and changed the owner of the home folder from 'staff' to me, using the chown command. Here is an excellent tutorial on how to do this in a bash shell : gd.tuwien.ac.at/linuxcommand.org/lts0070.html